# Why is it a convention to use gamma to denote a curve?

Tags: notation, convention

Why is it a convention to use $\gamma$ to denote a curve?

(This is a meta question, but I couldn't find a "meta mathematics" stackexchange, so I'm trying here.)

Comment: You may also post your question on https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is hard to imagine that there is such an explicit "convention"... Maybe sometimes used for the link with the mathematician [Camille Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Jordan), which obviously [did not use it](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/jordan/jordan.pdf).

Comment: Another possible source is simple that $\gamma$ is the **third** letter of the Greek alphabet, thus corersponding to the $c$ of *curve*.